# How to import Configurable product from csv with custom attributes using php script

Tags: magento2, database, configurable-product, csv, import-products

I am trying to import a configurable products in magento 2 with custom attributes using a php script. How far I got the php script to create simple product without custom attributes as a newbie i don't know too much about magento 2. If you could help. I shall be very thankful to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample script to create configurable products. You can modify to suit your needs.

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.1/dev/tests/integration/testsuite/Magento/ConfigurableProduct/_files/product_configurable.php

Comment: Does it add Additional attributes vaues also?